# How can I apply weights in this scipy least squares optimization routine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, linear-regression, least-squares

I am trying to do a generalized least squares fit to find the best fitting line through some (`x,y`) data points. I was able to do this via scipy, but I am having trouble applying weights. I would like to get the weights from the residuals of the original fit and attempt a refitting via least squares using the weights. The weights should be the inverse of the residuals, but since `-1 < residuals < 1` and this is just an example, I'm okay with using the residuals as the weights.

The (`x,y`) data points are calculated elsewhere, and the goal is to find an alpha (1/slope) and intercept for the best fitting line `y = x/alpha + intercept`.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

ydata = [9.7372923, 10.0587245, 10.3838510, 10.6931371, 10.9616260, 11.1833220, 11.3806770, 11.5248917, 11.7353000]
xdata = np.array([j+5 for j in range(len(ydata))])

def get_weights(resid):
    """
    This function calculates the weights per (x,y) by using the inverse of the squared residuals divided by the total sum of the inverse of the squared residuals. 
    This might be incorrect but should work for the sake of example. 
    """
    total = sum([abs(resid[i]) for i in range(len(resid))])
    fract = np.array([resid[i]/total for i in range(len(resid))])
    return fract

def get_least_squares_fit(xs, ys):
    """
    This function finds alpha (1/slope) and the y-intercept in the equation
    of a line y = x / alpha + intercept = mx + b
    """
    ## SPECIFY INITIAL GUESS OF OPTIMIZED PARAMETERS
    params_guess = [1/3, 9] ## ps = [alpha, intercept]
    ## DEFINE FITTING FUNCTIONS
    fit_func = lambda ps,x : x/ps[0] + ps[1]
    err_func = lambda ps,x,y : fit_func(ps,x) - y
    ## GET OPTIMIZED PARAMETERS, RESIDUALS & WEIGHTS
    res = least_squares(err_func, params_guess, args=(xs, ys))
    alpha, intercept, residuals = res.x[0], res.x[1], res.fun
    weights = get_weights(residuals)
    return alpha, intercept, residuals, weights

alpha, intercept, residuals, weights = get_least_squares_fit(xdata, ydata)

print(alpha, intercept)
>> 4.03378447722 8.6198247828

print(residuals)
>>  [ 0.12206326  0.04853721 -0.02868313 -0.09006308 -0.11064582 -0.08443567
-0.03388451  0.06980694  0.1073048 ]
```

I get identical results using [`scipy curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), which has `sigma` and `absolute_sigma`. I'm guessing this is the best way to proceed. I'm still trying to figure it out though.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to achieve your overall goal to perform a relative regression on the original data, fitting to the lowest sum of squared relative error, rather than fitting to the lowest sum of squared absolute error?

Comment: That would be sufficient for this example. I'm more concerned with how to apply the weights rather than the weights themselves; the absolute square was just a guess on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this works correctly. The idea is that each residual should be multiplied with the corresponding weight. The function to minimize is the sum of these products. Rather than use an external module to do the least squares fitting, I used good ol' `scipy.optimize.minimize`, which gives identical results for the unweighted least squares fit (`get_gls_fit(..., weights=None, ...)`) and the results of the external modules.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
## same xdata and ydata as stated in question

def guess_initial_parameters(xs, ys):
    """
    xs          :   type<list> or type<array>
    ys          :   type<list> or type<array>
    """
    ## GUESS SLOPE
    slope = (ys[-1]-ys[0])/(xs[-1]-xs[0])
    alpha = 1/slope
    ## GUESS INTERCEPT
    intercept = np.mean([ys[-1] - xs[-1]/alpha, ys[0] - xs[0]/alpha])
    return [alpha, intercept]

def update_weights(residuals, power=1):
    """
    residuals   :   type<list> or type<array>
    power       :   type<float>
    """
    ## INVERT RESIDUALS
    invs = [1/residuals[idr] for idr in range(len(residuals))]
    ## NORMALIZE RESIDUALS
    invs = [abs(inv)**power for inv in invs]
    total = sum(invs)
    return [invs[idv]/total for idv in range(len(invs))]

def fit_func(ps, xs):
    """
    ps          :   [alpha, intercept]
    xs          :   type<list> or type<array>
    """
    ## FIT TO EQUATION OF LINE
    return [xs[idx]/ps[0] + ps[1] for idx in range(len(xs))] ## alpha = 1/slope

def get_residuals(ps, xs, ys):
    """
    ps          :   [alpha, intercept]
    xs          :   type<list> or type<array>
    ys          :   type<list> or type<array>
    """
    ## GET LINEAR FIT
    ys_trial = fit_func(ps, xs)
    ## GET RESIDUALS
    residuals = [(ys[idx] -  ys_trial[idx])**2 for idx in range(len(ys))]
    return residuals

def err_func(ps, xs, ys, wts):
    """
    ps          :   [alpha, intercept]
    xs          :   type<list> or type<array>
    ys          :   type<list> or type<array>
    wts         :   type<list> or type<array>
    """
    ## GET RESIDUALS
    residuals = get_residuals(ps, xs, ys)
    ## SUM WEIGHTED RESIDUALS
    return sum([wts[idr] * residuals[idr] for idr in range(len(residuals))])

def get_gls_fit(xs, ys, ps_init, weights=None, power=2, routine='Nelder-Mead'):
    """
    xs          :   type<list> or type<array>
    ys          :   type<list> or type<array>
    ps_init     :   [alpha, intercept]
    weights     :   None or type<list> or type<array>
    power       :   type<float>
    routine     :   'Nelder-Mead'
    """
    ## GET INITIAL PARAMETER GUESS
    if type(ps_init) == (list or np.array):
        pass
    elif ps_init == 'estimate':
        ps_init = guess_initial_parameters(xs, ys)
    else:
        raise ValueError("ps_init = type<list> or type<array> or 'estimate'")
    ## GET WEIGHTS
    if weights is None:
        wts = np.ones(len(xs))
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>\nORDINARY LEAST SQUARES (OLS) FIT:")
    else:
        wts = weights[:]
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>\nGENERALIZED LEAST SQUARES (GLS) FIT:")
    ## MINIMIZE SUM OF WEIGHTED RESIDUALS
    ans = optimize.minimize(err_func, x0=ps_init, args=(xs, ys, wts,), method=routine)
    ## GET OPTIMIZED PARAMETERS
    alpha, intercept = ans.x[0], ans.x[1]
    ## GET RESIDUALS
    residuals = np.array(get_residuals([alpha, intercept], xs, ys))
    ## GET UPDATED WEIGHTS FOR REFITTING
    wts_upd = np.array(update_weights(residuals, power))
    ## PRINT & RETURN RESULTS
    print("\n   ALPHA = %.3f, INTERCEPT = %.3f" %(alpha, intercept))
    print("\n   RESIDUALS:  \n", residuals)
    print("\n   WEIGHTS (used): \n", wts)
    print("\n   WEIGHTS (updated):  \n", wts_upd, "\n\n")
    return [alpha, intercept], residuals, wts_upd
```

Output:

```
[alpha_og, intercept_og], residuals_og, wts_og = get_gls_fit(xdata, ydata, ps_init='estimate')
[alpha_up, intercept_up], residuals_up, wts_up = get_gls_fit(xdata, ydata, ps_init=[alpha_og, intercept_og], weights=wts_og)

>>>>>>>>>>>
ORDINARY LEAST SQUARES (OLS) FIT:

   ALPHA = 4.034, INTERCEPT = 8.620

   RESIDUALS:  
 [ 0.01489916  0.00235566  0.00082289  0.00811204  0.01224353  0.00713032
  0.0011486   0.00487199  0.01151256]

   WEIGHTS (used): 
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]

   WEIGHTS (updated):  
 [ 0.00179424  0.07177589  0.58819594  0.00605264  0.002657    0.00783406
  0.3019051   0.01678001  0.00300511] 


>>>>>>>>>>>
GENERALIZED LEAST SQUARES (GLS) FIT:

   ALPHA = 3.991, INTERCEPT = 8.621

   RESIDUALS:  
 [  1.86965273e-02   4.34039033e-03   7.51041961e-05   4.53922546e-03
   7.27337443e-03   3.18112777e-03   1.00990091e-05   1.06473505e-02
   2.05510268e-02]

   WEIGHTS (used): 
 [ 0.00179424  0.07177589  0.58819594  0.00605264  0.002657    0.00783406
  0.3019051   0.01678001  0.00300511]

   WEIGHTS (updated):  
 [  2.86578120e-07   5.31749819e-06   1.77597366e-02   4.86184846e-06
   1.89362088e-06   9.89925930e-06   9.82216884e-01   8.83653134e-07
   2.37190819e-07]
```